# Authentication provider per url pattern - Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I faced problem when configuring different auth providers per url pattern using Spring Boot security. I am trying to configure security in Spring Boot app and want to have swagger behind basic auth and all API is secured only by token. I have it almost working, but noticed that API except the fact that it is secured by token which is verified by IDAuthProvider class it also is secured by basic auth. I do not want that and also noticed that if I removed line:
                    `sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).`
it seems to be working correctly, but still header Basic {token} is being added in request which is something I do not want... 
Do you know how can I configure it to make all swagger stuff secured by basic auth and API stuff secured by token?

My configuration looks like below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public class SwaggerSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        private final AuthenticationProvider userPassAuthProvider;

        @Autowired
        SwaggerSecurityConfig(UserPassAuthProvider userPassAuthProvider) {
            this.userPassAuthProvider = userPassAuthProvider;
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.antMatcher("/swagger**").
                    authorizeRequests().
                    antMatchers("/swagger**").authenticated().
                    and().httpBasic().and().csrf().disable();
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
                throws Exception {
            auth.authenticationProvider(userPassAuthProvider);
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public class APISecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        private final AuthenticationProvider idAuthProvider;

        @Autowired
        APISecurityConfig(IDAuthProvider idAuthProvider) {
            this.idAuthProvider = idAuthProvider;
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.antMatcher("/api/v1/**").
                    authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().
                    and().
                    addFilterBefore(idpAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class).sessionManagement().
                    and().
                    csrf().disable();
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
                throws Exception {
            auth.authenticationProvider(idAuthProvider);
        }

        IDPAuthenticationFilter idpAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager auth) {
            return new IDPAuthenticationFilter(auth, new OrRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher(ApiRouter.API_PATH + "/**", HttpMethod.GET.toString()), new AntPathRequestMatcher(ApiRouter.API_PATH + "/**", HttpMethod.POST.toString()), new AntPathRequestMatcher(ApiRouter.API_PATH + "/**", HttpMethod.DELETE.toString()),  new AntPathRequestMatcher("/swagger**", HttpMethod.GET.toString())));
        }
    }
}
```